# Blank grey screen after MacBook boots halfway

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a MacBook Pro from late 2011 (8,2). When I hit the power button, I hear the chime, then I see the apple logo, then a progress bar appears underneath. It goes to about halfway, then suddenly turns black, then fades to grey. And then nothing. It's not responsive to any keystrokes or clicks. The processor runs really hot and the fans run at full speed. Both fans are running properly.

Booting to safe mode gives the same result, as does trying to boot to the recovery partition or using Internet Recovery. When choosing the boot device, the only option is the recovery disk. That doesn't work either.

Resetting the NVRAM/PRAM and SMC have done nothing.

Single user mode is no help either. It doesn't let me mount the drive because "disk1s1 is write locked".

I've tried disconnecting the hard drive, wifi adapter, and optical drive, all to no avail. I've also tried only using one stick of RAM at a time (neither of which seem to be original, as they're 2 sticks of 8GB ram, although they're compatible according to Crucial's website).

I'm totally at a loss here. I've spent the entire day on this and have no idea what to do. I've looked all over Apple Stack exchange. Even Apple Support couldn't help me.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Funny, I am having the same problem. My Macbook is early 2011, but the problem you are describing looks like exactly my problem. I have no solution at the moment. Even the recovery software does not boot.

Comment: @Christian I've successfully installed Windows but that has done nothing to help the situation unfortunately.

Comment: So, in 2017 the "just works" principle was replaced with "to fix macOS, install Windows". What a sad age we are living in. I am trying to reinstall SnowLeo from DVD, hopefully without deleting old data.

Comment: I fixed my problem with letting some guy replacing my graphics chip, which was broken. He said, this is often the case with that kind of models. Apple often replaces teh whole Logic board which is pretty expensive. This guy did it for around 110 € and sent back the fixed machine + the replaced graphics chip.